# I can't seem to connect to a wireless network on my HP mini

Tags: kubuntu

I recently installed **Kubuntu 17.04** on my old **HP mini**.  When I tried connecting to the internet wirelessly, no connections showed up.  It only says "Networks Disconnected"  I'm very new to Linux Operating Systems, so I apologize in advance if I'm confused on your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling secure-boot in the BIOS. And if nothing changes when the operating system is running restart network-manager. (`service network-manager restart`). Please let me know if this works, if not I will remove answer.

Comment: Hello, I tried looking for a secure boot option under Security and System Configuration, but couldn't find it.  I think the reason is because my laptop used to run Windows 7, and the hardware at the time didn't support a secure boot option.

Comment: @Batstud Hmm. Well if it doesn't exist on your machine it shouldn't be a problem.